# If "top" indicates CPU is spending 10% on %wa (iowait), does that mean the CPU is idle?

Tags: linux, operating-systems, cpu-usage, top, iowait

I am referring to the Linux `top` command.  If it indicates 10.4% was spent on `wa`, does that mean 10.4% CPU was available for other processes?

```
top - 09:40:45 up 178 days, 34 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.32, 0.43, 0.42
Tasks: 173 total,   1 running, 172 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 1.3%us,  1.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 87.2%id,  10.4%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wa is the time the CPU is waiting for I/O to complete.
87.2%id is the amount of CPU spends in idle, and therefore would be available for other processes.

Comment: Not entirely true, if I have understood your answer correctly. Both wa (IO wait) *and* id (idle) time are available for other processes to use.

Answer (score 1):

The percentage expressed in `wa` (IOwait) does not convey idle time on the CPU. It could indeed be idle or it could be being used by another process.

The percentage expressed in `id` (idle) does not express total idle time either, this is idle-time not otherwise allocated. The percentage of CPU time available for other processes can be expressed as 100 -  `us` (user) - `sy` (system) .